# How to check if any app is installed during XCTest?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest

I need to check if an app with a particular `bundleIdentifier` is installed on the active device or Simulator and I need to do this from an XC UI test.

I've tried doing:

```swift
import XCTest

class ServerLoop: XCTestCase {
  func testRunAppInstalled() async throws {
    let app = XCUIApplication("pl.bartekpacia.SomeApp")
    if app.exists {
      // code
    }
  }
}
```

but unfortunately it only tells me if the app is currently open, not installed.

I want to be able to check if *any app* is installed, not only my apps. I need this because if the app with `bundleId` is not installed and I do `XCUIApplication(bundleId)`, then the test fails and there's no way to prevent it from doing so.

Comment: Just an idea: Give someapp a custom scheme. If you are able to open that scheme, the app is installed. (I suggest this because it's how my app learns whether certain other apps are installed.)

Comment: How can I add a custom scheme to, say, com.apple.Maps or com.apple.preferences? I edited the question to make my intent more clear.

Comment: Maps has a custom scheme you can check for. I do not know what `com.apple.preferences` refers to.

Comment: `com.apple.preferences` is the Settings.app :)

Comment: This won't get me far anyway, because I'm writing a testing framework and the bundleId comes from my user-developer, so it could be basically anything.

Comment: The Settings app cannot not be present.

Comment: Well then you are up against the limitations of iOS. It doesn't let you do what you want to do. It would be best to stop wanting that.

Comment: Settings.app was just an example. But yeah, that's what I was afraid of. I was just thinking that maybe the OS is more liberal during UI integration testing. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense (you're not "inside" the app in the usual way) but I don't think so....

Comment: Let's leave this here, though, and see if anyone comes along with different info

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make it work with the bundle identifier. But if you have the name of the app as it is visible on springboard, this code works in my tests:

```
func test_existence() {
    let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
    let appIcon = springboard.icons["Settings"]
    if appIcon.exists {
        print("YEAH!")
    } else {
        XCTFail()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's _some solution_, but then we become language-dependent.

Comment: Yes, thats' unfortunately true. I worked with the bundle identifier a few years ago. But Apple removed it. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the SpringBoard solution is a good one.

You could also attempt a launch of an XCUIApplication and expect a fail on the test with XCTExpectFailure in nonStrict mode, with the continueAfterFailure property on XCTestCase set to true.